# how to make a modal and slideshow for each image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, gallery

in application i have several gallery contain tens of images per gallery i used bootstrap and did something like below code but image modal is going to be show on right alignment not in center.

```
<img  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" width="200" hight="200" src="images/10001281_1418834638375344_6048578890971989138_n.jpg"> 
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <img src="images/10001281_1418834638375344_6048578890971989138_n.jpg"> 
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap uses modal for different media sizes with 600px width check that images fit in 600px width

also you can add twitter-bootstrap slideshow "carousel" in each cearosal.

Comment: did you mean in each modal? in ...add twitter-bootstrap slideshow "carousel" in each cearosal